# How to I get values from this nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

`var_dump($ib);` gives me the following output:

```
array (
  'data' => array (
    0 => array ( 
      'id' => '2015469353355_151',
      'from' => array ( 
         'name' => 'Aah',
         'id' => '100000292544713',
      ),
      'message' => 'zzzz',
      'created_time' => '2012-06-08T06:16:41+0000',
      ),
    1 => array (
      'id' => '2015469353355_152',
      'from' => array (
        'name' => 'assaaaa',
        'id' => '100000292544713',
      ),
      'message' => 'zzzz',
      'created_time' => '2012-06-08T06:16:51+0000',
    ),
  ),
  'paging' => array (
    'previous' => 'https://graph.facebook.com/2015469353355/comments?limit=25&value=1&redirect=1&__paging_token=2015469353355_175&access_token=AAAFfJS6rRAABAHKGZCy57ZCrSEdQL2kUIYqZAcNBLkbnKTBxRhhx9CTvnUlq2LcAK1kZBWnV6AH5RpvkmGYRFzvk12kNXLe6OhjjapH5PEIUwv1h2tYl&since=1340009948&__previous=1',
  'next' => 'https://graph.facebook.com/2015469353355/comments?limit=25&value=1&redirect=1&access_token=AAAFfJS6rRAABAHKGZCy57ZCrSEdQL2kUIYqZAcNBLkbnKTBxRhhx9CTvnUlq2LcAK1kZBWnV6AH5RpvkmGYRFzvk12kNXLe6OhjjapH5PEIUwv1h2tYl&until=1340009948&__paging_token=2015469353355_175',
  ),
)
```

How do I retrieve the value of **'next'** ?

Comment: I think `print_r` gives this type of output not `var_dump`...

Comment: what was the point of -4 here?

Comment: @vlz - Checkout the original post.  Was heavily un​​​​formatted.  Perhaps that is the reason...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `paging` is an index of your main array, and it, in itself is *also* an array.  You can use its indexes to drill down and get to the information you need.

`$ib['paging']` will give you -

```
paging => array (
  'previous' => '...',
  'next' => '...',
)
```

Then the next step is to drill down into the array your got back one more time to the `next` index.  so what you end up with is a statement that specifies an index within an index.

```
$ib['paging']['next'];
```

---

If the `next` parameter was **also** an array, you could even go further down and use another index -

```
paging => array (
  'previous' => '...',
  'next' => array(
     'url'=>'https://graph.facebook...'
  ),
)

// this will give us `'https://graph.facebook...'`
echo $ib['paging']['next']['url'];
```

Comment: No problem!  Be sure to vote on the other answers as they are also 100% correct!

Answer (score 5):

You can get the value of `next` by doing the following,

```
echo $ib['paging']['next'];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$array["paging"]['next']
```

If we assume that the main array is assigned to the variable `$array`